# Is there a way to request a data-type or text label on the form on Laravel 5.7?

Tags: php, laravel

Is there a way to request a data-type or text label on the form on Laravel 5.7?
Note: I already know that I can put it on the hidden input, but I just want it on the label or any HTML attribute.

Comment: I don't really get your question, can you give some examples?

Comment: instead of getting the input value as a request. is there a way to request a label or attribute. in the controller. aside from putting hidden input.

Comment: Honestly the question is still unclear.

Comment: You can pass extra data to controller by appending to form URL query string.

Answer (score 0):

When a form is submitted, the HTTP request only contains the field values, and the URL and METHOD attributes. It does not contain any other HTML attributes. If you want to pass additional data to the controller, you can either append it to the form URL, or add it as a hidden input. You could use JavaScript, to extract other attributes, and append it to the form prior to submission.